# Django: How to render/refresh web page multiple times

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm not sure how to render/refresh page multiple times during one execution.

Example: I'm running selenium tests on the background and I would like to update page after each run.

Each test returning some data and separately they are working perfectly.

```
def runtest1(request):
    title = Task.objects.get(test_name='runtest1').title
    test_result = calculate_words(title)
    update_tests('runtest1', test_result)
    return test_result


def runtest2(request):
    title = Task.objects.get(test_name='runtest2').title
    test_result = test_links(title)
    update_tests('runtest2', test_result)
    return test_result
```

and then render

```
def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    test_result = TestResult('', '', '')

    if request.GET.get('runtest1'):
        test_result = runtest1(request)

    if request.GET.get('runtest2'):
        test_result = runtest2(request)

    context = {'tasks': tasks, 'test_result': test_result}
    return render(request, 'tasks/list.html', context)
```

I would like to run all these tests in one run and update page after each test.

Something like this:

```
def run_all(request):
    runtest1(request)
    runtest2(request)
    return runtest3(request)
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue?